# pattern split to get all values in a string representing object

Tags: java, regex

I have Strings that represent rows in a table like this:

```
{failures=4, successes=6, name=this_is_a_name, p=40.00}
```

I made an expression that can be used with `Pattern.split()` to get me back all of the values in a `String[]`:

```
[\{\,](.*?)\=
```

In the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/jH9uW8/2) it works well with the exception of the ending `}`.

But when I actually run the pattern against my first row I get a `String[]` where the first element is an empty string. I only want the 4 values (**not keys**) from each row not the extra empty value.

```
Pattern getRowValues = Pattern.compile("[\\{\\,](.*?)\\=");
String[] row = getRowValues.split("{failures=4, successes=6, name=this_is_a_name, p=40.00}");
//CURRENT
//row[0]=> ""
//row[1]=>"4"
//row[2]=>"6"
//row[3]=>"this_is_a_name"
//row[4]=>"40.00}"

//WANT
//row[0]=>"4"
//row[1]=>"6"
//row[2]=>"this_is_a_name"
//row[3]=>"40.00"
```

Comment: Strip off the leading `{` and trailing `}` (e.g. using `substring`), then just split on `", "`

Comment: @AndyTurner no doubt a better solution, but for the sake of this question i would like to solve using the regex. thank you for the reply.

Comment: OK: `getRowValues.replaceAll("^{|}$", "").split(", ")`. All done with regex.

Comment: @AndyTurner will test now, would love it posted as an answer with any short explanation. thank you

Comment: Is `[, 4, 6, this_is_a_name, 40.00}]` your expected output?
`

Comment: @YassinHajaj , I edited my post a minute ago with what i get and what i would like. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = getRowValues
    // Strip off the leading '{' and trailing '}'
    .replaceAll("^\\{|\\}$", "")
    // then just split on comma-space
    .split(", ");
```

If you want just the values:

```
String[] parts = getRowValues
    // Strip off the leading '{' and up to (but no including) the first =,
    // and the trailing '}'
    .replaceAll("^\\{[^=]*|\\}$", "")
    // then just split on comma-space and up to (but no including) the =
    .split(", [^=]*");
```

Comment: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0` referring to ^

Comment: Missed the escaping on the `{}`.

Comment: gives me key:value, i bolded my question to highlight i just want all values. +1 because it gives me most i can work with this thank you

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

Modify your regular expression to `[{,](.*?)=|[}]` where I removed all the unnecessarily escaped characters in each of the  `[...]` constructs and added the `|[}]`

See also [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH9uW8/4)

## Option 2

```
=([^,]*)[,}]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- capture all the substrings after the `=` and before the `,` or close `}`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yF2gG7/1

**Sample text**

```
{failures=4, successes=6, name=this_is_a_name, p=40.00}
```

**Capture groups**

Each match gets the following capture groups:

- Capture group 0 gets the entire substring from `=` to `,` or `}`
- Capture group 1 gets just the value not including the `=`, `,`, or `}` characters

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = =4,
[0][1] = 4

[1][0] = =6,
[1][1] = 6

[2][0] = =this_is_a_name,
[2][1] = this_is_a_name

[3][0] = =40.00}
[3][1] = 40.00
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [,}]                     any character of: ',', '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When i do `row.split("[{,](.*?)=|[}]")` from option one, i still get a string array of length 5 with the first element being empty.